# How do I have to configre XAMPP so that it executds <?php ... ?> in html documents?

Tags: php, html, xampp

I am trying to have XAMPP's Apache execute `<?php ... ?` that is embedded in a HTML document:

```
<html>
<head><title>abc</title></head>
<body>

<?php
  echo("bla");
?>

</body>
</html>
```

However, the `<?php ... ?>` part is not "executed" and transferred to the browser verbatim.

I suppose there is a configuration file that I have to change so that the piece of php is executed.

Comment: i assume that you have called your file `something.php` and not `something.html` ?

Comment: It's called `something.html`.

Comment: You can't run PHP in an html page ending with `.html` Change file extension to `.php` See the second link on top of your question.

Comment: @Dlk Why can't they run `.html` files as PHP?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Can they ? Didn’t know that they can Without htaccess.

Comment: @Dlk Oh sure they can :) See the 2nd duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know XAMPP already includes PHP, but unless you end the script name with .php it is unlikely to be processed by the PHP engine.

If you are trying to use `php` inside `.html` file then 
try adding `.htaccess` file or changing apache config with the following line:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html
```

Or try the following,

Stop the apache service, then add one change in c:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf in the  section by adding...

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

Restart apache!

Hope this will help.